# Can't add extension method to IConfiguration in .NET Core (but working on other classes)

Tags: c#, .net-core, extension-methods

I've added the following extension method to my project.

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration self, string path)
  {
    IConfigurationSection section = self.GetSection(path);
    T output = section.Get<T>();

    return output;
  }
}
```

For some reason, it seems not to come through in intellisense and the compiler nags that a string can't be passed as a second argument. Googling verified that extension methods do work on interfaces and that the only requirement is that the signature differs, as they can't override.

> You can use extension methods to extend a class or interface, but not to override them. An extension method with the same name and signature as an interface or class method will never be called.

The way I see it, they do differ, because the original has a different pass in parameter than my string version.

```
public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration self, string x) { ... }
public static T Get<T>(this IConfiguration self, Action<BinderOptions> x) { ... }
```

Extending for another class seems to work too [as described at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

What am I missing?

Comment: @JoeSewell I believe you're mistaken due to assumptions (that in many cases are appropriate but not here). The error message would in this particular case mislead potential researcher. Also, technically speaking, it's two different messages, none of which actually relates to the issue, so the diagnostics would be unlikely to lead to those. After checking with my network, the current phrasing seemed most helpful. Regrettably, there are cases where the error message won't do. This is such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that VS2019 cannot recognize the extension method with signature that has already been imported.

You should be able to use the extension method by using a namespace containing the class.

```
using <yourextensionmethodnamespace>;
```

And then calling it like this

```
configuration.Get<WhateverType>("key");
```

Comment: There you go! What a gotcha... It did work in VS17, if I recall correctly, didn't it?

Comment: Cannot recall facing this issue in previous versions of VS. Unable to check this out unfortunately to be 100% confident. I also feel like the intellisense works a bit different in VS19 comparing to VS17.